# millis(); Arduino "out of scope"

Tags: c++, scope, arduino-ide

I have build a custom clock / weatherstation. But for a couple of purposes I wanna be able to run timers inside my code. I have done this many times before in C++ with the SDL lib (SDL_GetTicks()). And I know I can get ticks the same way in the Arduino IDE by using millis().

So I just copy pasted my code for a previous timer class I used for SDL programs and just replaced the SDL_GetTicks() with millis().

However, now it says millis() is out of scope. Which I dont understand?
Am i not allowed to use millis inside member variables?

```
#include "Timer.h"

namespace Timer
 {
void Timer::startTimer() 
{
if (!this->timerStarted) 
{ 
  this->current_time = millis(); 
  this->timerStarted = true; 
}
} 

 unsigned int Timer::showTimePassed() 
{ 
 this->time_passed = millis(); 
 return this->time_passed - this->current_time; 
}

bool Timer::ifTimePassed(unsigned int timePassed)
{
this->last_time = millis();
if (!this->timerStarted)
{
  this->current_time = millis();
  this->timerStarted = true;
}

if (this->timerStarted == true && this->last_time >= this->current_time + timePassed)
{
  timerStarted = false;
  return true;
}
return false;
}

void Timer::setLoop()
{
this->timerStarted = true;
this->last_time = this->current_time;
this->current_time = millis();
this->time_passed = this->current_time - this->last_time;
}

unsigned int Timer::getLoopTime()
{
return this->time_passed;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you are allowed to use the function `millis` inside a class method. Could you quote the **exact** error message, that always helps, and also indicate which line of your code the error message applies to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to include arduino.h in your header file, this should solve the problem.

#include <Arduino.h>